# Using Create-React-App with Apache VirtualHost

Tags: reactjs, apache, localhost, create-react-app, virtualhost

I am trying to develop a project for a company. This company has an API that only allows requests from two sources: Their own host, and `xyz.localhost`.

At first, I developed the project with jQuery only (loaded in via CDN). With an Apache VirtualHost setup, this worked -- I could access the API.

Now, I want to refactor the project and use React with it. I used `create-react-app` to create a react directory.

The problem is: I can get create-react-app to use `xyz.localhost`, but I am still getting the CORS error message in Chrome:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://api.thatcompany.com/search?search=a' 
from origin 'http://xyz.localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

Has anybody any ideas how to make it work?
Thank you in advance.

---

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/*.conf
```

/private/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       xyz.localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             xyz.localhost
```

/private/etc/apache2/vhosts/xyz.localhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Users/MYUSERNAME/dev_projects/MY-REACT-APP/public"
        ServerName xyz.localhost

        <Directory "/Users/MYUSERNAME/dev_projects/MY-REACT-APP/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
                FileETag None
                <ifModule mod_headers.c>
                        Header unset ETag
                        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
                        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
                        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
                </ifModule>
        </filesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

My create-react-app start script:

```
"scripts": { "start": "HOST=xyz.localhost react-scripts start" }
```

Comment: When you run `npm start`, did you have any error?  Does your app use api `http://api.thatcompany.com/search?search=a`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

I simply pointed the VirtualHost to the build folder of Create React App, this worked and served me the static files.

Editing the code was pretty tiresome, as I had to run `npm run Build` after every update.

Luckily, I found the `npm watch` module. With that, create react App would rebuild on every save. I still have to wait a second between save and refreshing the browser, and it’s absolutely not comparable to using create react app on its own, but it was a good enough solution!